# UILabel.text is not being set

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

In my code I am attempting to just set the text of a UILabel.  The function doing this is being called, and everything inside it executes as expected, except for the UILabel.text assignment.  Below is the gist of the code being run:

```
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    var count2 = count

    ref.child(String(count2-3)).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot2) in
        var hitterRef = snapshot2.childSnapshotForPath("/Hitter")
        var pitcherRef = snapshot2.childSnapshotForPath("/Pitcher")
        var playRef = snapshot2.childSnapshotForPath("/Play")

        var play = String(playRef.childSnapshotForPath("/Name").value!)
        var outs = playRef.childSnapshotForPath("/Outs").value! as! Int
        var rbi = playRef.childSnapshotForPath("/RBI").value! as! Int

        assignScore(play, outs: outs, rbis: rbi, pitcherSelected: pitcherSelected, ResultsLabel: ResultsLabel, playName: playName, pointDiff: pointDiff)
    })
    print("successful delay")
    count2++
}

func assignScore(play:String, outs:Int, rbis:Int, pitcherSelected:Bool, ResultsLabel: UILabel, playName: UILabel, pointDiff: UILabel){
    var playScore = 0.0

    print("assign score is running")
    if(pitcherSelected == true) {

        /*
        *Below section covers the outs of the batter selected
        */
        //below means that the user has selected the batter
        if(outs == 0){
            if(play == "Walk") {
                //this means that the pitcher walked the batter
                playScore -= 0.5

            }else {
                //means just a regular out
                //nothing happens
            }
        }
    }
    ResultsLabel.text = "Test Text"
    print("Below text test")
}
```

Comment: Double check that the ResultsLabel IBOutlet is actually connected to the label in your storyboard. Also, it is recommended to name your variables with lower camel case, so resultsLabel rather than ResultsLabel is preferred.

Comment: Is `observeSingleEventOfType` doing its work in a background thread? If so you would need to ensure the actual UI change, ie. the label text update, is done on the main thread.

Comment: @Magnas `observeSingleEventOfType` is an asynchronous function, which is where `assignScore()` is being called.  But I know the asynchronous call is completed however the UI change isn't.  Can you not alter the UI in an async function or something?

Comment: Yes that's right all UI updates should be done on the main thread so, if memory serves, inside something like `DispatchQueue.main.async {
}`